# I got a mistake when I run the this code:

Tags: php, mysql

```
$result = "Insert into insert_data (namapelajar1, namapelajar2, 
            namapelajar3, nopendaftaran1,nopendaftaran2,nopendaftaran3) 
          values                
         ('$namapelajar1','$namapelajar2','$namapelajar3',
          '$nopendaftaran1', '$nopendaftaran2','$nopendaftaran3',
          '$kelas', '$tajukprojek');";
```

It always prompt

> Parse error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$result'
>   (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistem\insert_data.php on line 20

Any one can keep me some advise?? Many thanks!!

Comment: pls cmmt immediately

Comment: can you mention the datatypes of your columns ?

Comment: Maybe missing semicolon?

Comment: and there is an extra semi collon at the end where you close the bracket of values(..)

Comment: Error is one one line above so show us that line

Comment: I doubt you are using $result variable before above statement?

Comment: @MuhamamdUsman all your comments have nth to do with problem

Comment: 6 vs 8 ????? ? ?, u are missing `kelas, tajukprojek` columns, but u r getting Parse error in php right

Comment: the count of columns(6) and values(8) differ

Comment: If this is line 20, look at the line above. Your error has nothing to do with this particular code.

Comment: all data types is varchar

Comment: @KartikKathiresan right now you have php error which has nth to do with mysql. Error is cause because some lines above you have wrong code, probably mising semi colon, so show us code above

Comment: there is no Parse error: in your this code, yes, query having some problem, already highlited. share more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two extra column inside values only 6 field are specified but you enter 8 values. Try this

```
$result = " Insert into insert_data(namapelajar1,namapelajar2,namapelajar3,nopendaftaran1,nopendaftaran2,nopendaftaran3) values ('$namapelajar1','$namapelajar2','$namapelajar3','$nopendaftaran1','$nopendaftaran2','$nopendaftaran3')";
```

Comment: Thanks to Your Advice

Comment: @KartikKathiresan can you find out what was your error.

Comment: Any question about php, mysql or android studio error can ask here right

Comment: Error is Solved

Comment: @KartikKathiresan Oh Yes. If you got your desired output you can verify it.

Comment: Ok, I am now inserting data into mysql database using android studio but i want to insert 7 field can ahh?? Comment immediately

Comment: @KartikKathiresan Pardon